# Processing two forms into 1 submit button

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel, whm

I have a user registration form system. Everything works properly with this, it creates the Database with the users name, email and username MD5's the password and the confirmation code.

I have a domain registration form system. This works properly, creates the users domain and adds it into WHM. Biggest thing is, is how can I go about adding in the TWO forms into 1, as I have been working on this since 3 days ago. Yesterday was 6 hours, Today is a good 2 hours, and still nothing. When clicking on submit it only creates the users account, and nothing is done in the WHM.

Here is the code for it. The top code above [Domain Registration] is the user registration.

```
<form id='register' action='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript(); "<?=$PHP_SELF?>" ?>'  method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>

<fieldset >
<legend>Register</legend>
<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
<div class='short_explanation'>* required fields</div>
<input type='text'  class='spmhidip' name='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSpamTrapInputName(); ?>' />
<div><span class='error'><?php echo $fgmembersite->GetErrorMessage(); ?></span></div>

<div class='container'>
    <label for='name' >Your Full Name*: </label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='name' id='name' value='<?php echo $fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('name') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='register_name_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>

<div class='container'>
    <label for='email' >Email Address*:</label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='email' id='email' value='<?php echo $fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('email') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='register_email_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>

<div class='container'>
    <label for='username' >Username*:</label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='username' id='username' value='<?php echo $fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('username') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='register_username_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>

<div class='container' style='height:80px;'>
    <label for='password' >Password*:</label><br/>
    <div class='pwdwidgetdiv' id='thepwddiv' ></div>
    <noscript>
        <input type='password' name='Password' id='password' maxlength="50" />
    </noscript>    
    <div id='register_password_errorloc' class='error' style='clear:both'></div>
</div>

[<b>Domain Registration</b>]

<div class='container'>
    <label for='host' >Domain*:</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="Host"><br/>
</div>

<div class='container'>
    <label for='package' >Package*:</label><br/>
    <select name="Package">
    <option value="ihosting_Small">Small</option>
    <option value="ihosting_Medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="ihosting_Large">Large</select></option><br/>  
</div>

<div class='container'>
    <label for='username' >Username*:</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="Username">
    <span id='register_username_errorloc' class='error'></span>   
</div>

<div class='container'>
    <label for='password' >Password*:</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="Password" value="Password">
</div>

<div class='container'>
    <input type='submit' name="submitted" value='Submit' />
</div>

</fieldset>

</form>
```

This part:

```
<form id='register' action='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript(); "<?=$PHP_SELF?>" ?>' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
```

The first and last part is for the user and this: `<?=$PHP_SELF?>` is for the domain registration, both need to use the `action= method`, but I have been trying to figure out how to integrate it, because if I delete:

```
<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript();
```

the whole page disappears. Some how I don't think you can have to scripts needing the action= method. Both are vital and important.

I've even tried making it in 2 forms, and both having their own separate "Submit" button which creates 2 buttons and you need to quickly press both buttons in order for both to work.

And this is the PHP formats for the forms:

(Top is user bottom is domain)

I obviously deleted the username and password for the WHM file.

```
<?PHP

require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");

if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
   if($fgmembersite->RegisterUser())
   {
        $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("thank-you.html");
   }
}

?>

<?php

if(isset($_POST[project_submission])) {

    require_once('whm.php');

    $test= new whm;

    $test->init('hosting','user','pass');

    $Host = $_POST[Host];
    $User = $_POST[Username];
    $Pass = $_POST[Password];
    $Pack = $_POST[Package];

    $result = $test->createAccount($Host, $User, $Pass, $Pack); 

    if($result) 
    { 
        echo "submission successful!";
    } 
    else 
    {  
        echo "submission failed!";
    } 
} else {

?>
```

Here is the is the submit button for the user:

```
<input type='submit' name="submitted" value='Submit' />
```

and for the domain reg:

```
<input type="submit" name="project_submission" value="Submit">
```

I've already tried to rename both `name=` and the same in the PHP where it shows the names of the submit buttons to the same name, and yet nothing worked.

Comment: Not clear with your question though, what you want is you have two forms and you have to submit both at the same time, in that case try jquery ajax, submit form1 and on submit event of form1 submit form2

Comment: You'll need to combine those two form's controllers into one, you didn't post much of the backend of the scripting so I can't help you much there, but basically you can't have a form within a form. so you'll need to find some way of combining the two forms without disrupting the flow of any other pages.

Comment: Thanks for the info. If I were to post the backend of the scripting I'd have to post at least 3 huge files. But thank you for the info. I don't know jquery ajax. :P